# onReceive not getting called in Android Widget

Tags: java, android, android-widget

I have not been able to get my code to hit the onReceive method in my widget when a button is pressed.  Im pretty sure I have all the settings in the manifest correct and all the code right.  Am I missing something or do I have to add something to manifest to get this to work?

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <receiver android:name="Widget">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            <action android:name="com.sense.widget.Widget.REFRESH" />
            <action android:name="com.sense.widget.Widget.PAGE_NEXT" />
            <action android:name="com.sense.widget.Widget.PAGE_PREV" /> 
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widget_provider" />
    </receiver>
</application>
```

**Code**

```
public class Widget extends AppWidgetProvider {
public static String REFRESH = "Refresh";
public static String PAGE_NEXT = "Next";
public static String PAGE_PREV = "Previous";
RemoteViews remoteViews;
ComponentName kWidget;

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {

    remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, getClass());
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            intent, 0);

    intent.setAction(REFRESH);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.refresh, pendingIntent);

    intent = new Intent(context, getClass());
    intent.setAction(PAGE_NEXT);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.next, pendingIntent);

    intent = new Intent(context, getClass());
    intent.setAction(PAGE_PREV);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.prev, pendingIntent);

    kWidget = new ComponentName(context, Widget.class);
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(kWidget, remoteViews);

}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Toast.makeText(context, "here", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
}
```

}

**Provider**

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:minWidth="294dp"
android:minHeight="294dp"
android:updatePeriodMillis="100000"
android:initialLayout="@layout/main">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was on my `PendingIntent's` im using `getActivity` instead of `getBroadcast`

Answer (score 0):

Missing the show(); off your Toast :-)

```
Toast.makeText(context, "here", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Good catch!  however I am still not able to get to the onRecieve method via button press.

Comment: I don't think this is possible tbh. What are you trying to achieve? I think your coming at it from the wrong direction

Comment: I am trying to set some sort of onClickListener for my buttons.  I know this is not possible in a widget and I thought the correct way of handling was what I had above.